# How can I get an image from a direct download link in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I'm pulling records from a website and attempting to store one of the images it returns (a BMP file). The issue is, the website only returns a direct download link, no preview. A lot like [this link](https://repo.pw.edu.pl/docstore/download/WUT063b82396cca4d13bf98ebf5124401e8/Drozdziel.pdf) (but instead mine is a BMP not a PDF)

There's no preview, just an immediate download.

There doesn't appear to be a way to generate a different link, and I don't know how to handle this url with rails! I just need to save it to my project/local file tree. Any ideas?

Comment: Use ActiveStorage and generate thumbnails as you would normally.

Comment: You can use [Net:HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), [OpenURI](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) or any number of [HTTP client gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) to download files to your server. ActiveStorage also lets you create attachments from [file IO objects](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) such as an OpenURI stream.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform 3 operations: get the contents of the url, write them on disk and attach them to you model.

## Get contents of url

Ruby has various libraries to handle HTTP get requests. There is of course the standard library Net::HTTP and other HTTP client gems as [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) said. I have used some of them, my favorite choice is [http.rb](https://github.com/httprb/http) but you can choose whatever you like.

## Write stream to disk

You should choose a folder and a filename and write the stream.

## Attach data to model

There are several gems to deal with [attachments](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads) too. If you prefer [ActiveStorage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) you can check method `attach`

A naive implementation may look like this:

```rb
# You can use and other HTTP gem or standard Net::HTTP
gem 'http'
require 'http'

url = 'https://www.ruby-lang.org/images/header-ruby-logo.png'

# You can set timeouts and other options here
response = HTTP.follow(max_hops: 2).get(url)

# You can check for statuses or other responses
return if response.status != 200 || response.content_type.nil?

# You can grab filename from url or set another filename
filename = SecureRandom.hex

path = File.join('tmp', filename)

# Write stream somewhere
file = File.open(path, 'wb')
 response.body.each do |chunk|
  file.write(chunk)
end

# Suppose you use ActiveStorage, you can use the `attach` method
your_model.you_attribute.attach(
   io: File.open(path),
   filename: filename,
   content_type: response.content_type.mime_type
 )
```